# How to SUM() a column and write in another column in same table

Tags: sql, database, localdb

So i'm a newbie at programming and i need to store data.I have created Service-Based Database for store the data and i have a table like this.

| gameprice | gamedesc | gametotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | RDR2 |  |
| 40 | R6S |  |

I want to take gameprice column, sum it, and write to gametotal. I mean even if i add another game it will add new game price to current gametotal.

`Select Sum(gameprice) as gametotal From gametable`

like this

| gameprice | gamedesc | gametotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | RDR2 | 100 |
| 40 | R6S |  |

| gameprice | gamedesc | gametotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | RDR2 | 160 |
| 40 | R6S |  |
| 60 | DyingL2 |  |

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired result? It's not clear to me.

Comment: don't need gametotal column just run this query whenewer you need SELECT * FROM [YourTable] UNION ALL SELECT SUM(gameprice), 'Gametot' AS gamedesc FROM [YourTable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- make gt variable
DECLARE @gt INT;

-- clear GameTotal Column 
UPDATE GameTable SET GameTotal = NULL 

-- set gt value to game column total value
select @gt = sum(game) from GameTable;

-- insert @gt to GameTotal Column
INSERT INTO GameTable (GameTotal) values (@gt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking answer to be like below

[image: gameprice gamedesc 40 R6S 60 RDR2 100 Gametot]

If yes you can use below query

SELECT *
FROM [YourTable]
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(gameprice), 'Gametot' AS gamedesc FROM [YourTable]

Comment: yes, like this but it will be much better if gametotal can be a column.